# Ошибка при подключении к базе данных

Tags: php, html

Пишу личный кабинет по заказу одной знакомой. Впервые пишу на PHP и его знаю не то, чтобы в совершенстве, просто базовые знания, поэтому основную часть кода нагло ворую с этого сайта http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=347

До этого был только html, css, js, то есть такой эксперимент для меня в новинку:)

Так вот, я создал на виртуальном сервере wamp базу данных, в принципе всё, как в том уроке было, сделал, кое что поменял, чтобы потом из этого няшный дизайн сделать, дизайн, кстати, как бы уже готов, парсер при регистрации выводит вот такую печальную ошибку.

Что это за ошибка и что с ней делать?

Фото скрина прилагаю ссылкой из дропбокса, кто знает помогите, плиз))

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy8id4rsnlqw7xp/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA27.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @Byak, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент вы используете расширение mysql для работы с базой данных. В данной ошибке указано, что расширение mysql устарело и будет удалено в будущем. Используйте расширение mysqli (mysql improved, то есть навороченое, быстрое, надежное и т.д. mysql расширение). Или PDO. Для знакомства c mysqli тыкаем [сюда](http://php.net//manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) (тут выборка описывается, но по навигации найдете остальное), для знакомства c PDO тыкаем [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/302421/php-pdo-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85).

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря вам всё нашёл, но появилась ещё одна проблема, которую не могу решить сам, с mysqli всё работает и ошибок не выводит, но в базу данных заносится как id=1,2,3 и так далее, username=$username, password=$password, что делать?:D
Скриншот: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hltzo86qmmppyc9/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA.PNG?dl=0
Код: https://www.dropbox.com/s/let1lb3krgus21v/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA1.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Либо писать {$varname}, либо разрывать кавычки '.$varname.'

Comment: Забавно, пришёл к гениальной мысли и заработало вроде:)
Вот что получилось:
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES ('', '$username', '$password')");

Comment: Теперь появилась другая проблема: каждый раз когда я обновляю страницу с формой, в базу данных заносится новая строка с теми же id, login и password, какие я последние регистрировал в системе, то есть в базе данных у меня такое вот:  
https://www.dropbox.com/s/twmvjzwcdm9xg39/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA2.PNG?dl=0

Что делать?